# EditText addTextChangedListener cause memory leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I use [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) to check my app for memory leak,
and it reports a leak as follow
[image]

```
 public AutofitHelper setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    if (mEnabled != enabled) {
        mEnabled = enabled;

        if (enabled) {
            mTextView.addTextChangedListener(mTextWatcher);
            mTextView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(mOnLayoutChangeListener);

            autofit();
        } else {
        android.util.Log.i("linlian","AutofitHelper.setEnabled()remove="+mTextView);
            mTextView.removeTextChangedListener(mTextWatcher);
            mTextView.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(mOnLayoutChangeListener);

            mTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, mTextSize);
        }
    }
    return this;
}
```

the code calls `setEnable(true)` to add `addTextChangedListener` for TextView
and i have already added `setEnable(false)` to `removeTextChangedListener`, but
this is not enough, there is a static `TextLine.sCached` reference, how to 
release the `sCashed`.

The follow code snippet I found in TextLine

```
static TextLine recycle(TextLine tl) {
    tl.mText = null;
    tl.mPaint = null;
    tl.mDirections = null;

    tl.mMetricAffectingSpanSpanSet.recycle();
    tl.mCharacterStyleSpanSet.recycle();
    tl.mReplacementSpanSpanSet.recycle();

    synchronized(sCached) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sCached.length; ++i) {
            if (sCached[i] == null) {
                sCached[i] = tl;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

but, how to use it in correct way to recycle the static `sCashed`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a related topic [Android memory leak on textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30397356/android-memory-leak-on-textview-leakcanary-leak-can-be-ignored)

the Utils.clearTextLineCache() maybe a good workarounds.