# Android memory leak on textview - LeakCanary (Leak can be ignored)

Tags: android, memory-leaks, ddms, android-memory, leakcanary

I keep having the following memory leak as displayed by LeakCanary, when I go from my splash screen to the mainactivity. I understand that this is an expected leak due to fault in the Android OS itself, but is there a way I can avoid this (by setting specifics of some TextView somewhere?)

```
D/LeakCanary﹕ * LEAK CAN BE IGNORED.
D/LeakCanary﹕ * com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.views.ActivitySignUp_ has leaked:
D/LeakCanary﹕ * GC ROOT static android.text.TextLine.sCached
D/LeakCanary﹕ * references array android.text.TextLine[].[1]
D/LeakCanary﹕ * references android.text.TextLine.mCharacterStyleSpanSet
D/LeakCanary﹕ * references android.text.SpanSet.spans
D/LeakCanary﹕ * references array android.text.style.CharacterStyle[].[1]
D/LeakCanary﹕ * references com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.views.ActivitySignUp$2.this$0 (anonymous class extends android.text.style.ClickableSpan)
D/LeakCanary﹕ * leaks com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.views.ActivitySignUp_ instance
D/LeakCanary﹕ [ 05-22 08:54:52.160 13969:18091 D/LeakCanary ]
    * Reference Key: bb8124a9-2829-4ff3-8ded-13cf35f80f54
D/LeakCanary﹕ * Device: Genymotion generic Google Nexus 5 - 5.0.0 - API 21 - 1080x1920 vbox86p
D/LeakCanary﹕ * Android Version: 5.0 API: 21 LeakCanary: 1.3.1
D/LeakCanary﹕ * Durations: watch=10898ms, gc=137ms, heap dump=5529ms, analysis=9193ms
D/LeakCanary﹕ [ 05-22 08:54:52.160 13969:18091 D/LeakCanary ]
    * Details:
D/LeakCanary﹕ * Class android.text.TextLine
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   static $staticOverhead = byte[] [id=0x70622169;length=24;size=40]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   static sCached = android.text.TextLine[] [id=0x70775010;length=3]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   static DEBUG = false
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   static TAB_INCREMENT = 20
D/LeakCanary﹕ * Array of android.text.TextLine[]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   [0] = android.text.TextLine [id=0x1309a2e0]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   [1] = android.text.TextLine [id=0x12eed650]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   [2] = null
D/LeakCanary﹕ * Instance of android.text.TextLine
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   static $staticOverhead = byte[] [id=0x70622169;length=24;size=40]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   static sCached = android.text.TextLine[] [id=0x70775010;length=3]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   static DEBUG = false
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   static TAB_INCREMENT = 20
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mCharacterStyleSpanSet = android.text.SpanSet [id=0x12e32d80]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mChars = null
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mDirections = null
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mMetricAffectingSpanSpanSet = android.text.SpanSet [id=0x12e32d60]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mPaint = null
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mReplacementSpanSpanSet = android.text.SpanSet [id=0x12e32da0]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mSpanned = android.text.SpannedString [id=0x132dabe0]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mTabs = null
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mText = null
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mWorkPaint = android.text.TextPaint [id=0x1300f5c0]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mCharsValid = false
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mDir = 1
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mHasTabs = false
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mLen = 1
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mStart = 0
D/LeakCanary﹕ * Instance of android.text.SpanSet
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   classType = java.lang.Class [id=0x703bb448;name=android.text.style.CharacterStyle]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   spanEnds = int[] [id=0x1309fd60;length=2;size=24]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   spanFlags = int[] [id=0x1309fda0;length=2;size=24]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   spanStarts = int[] [id=0x1309fd20;length=2;size=24]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   spans = android.text.style.CharacterStyle[] [id=0x1309fce0;length=2]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   numberOfSpans = 1
D/LeakCanary﹕ * Array of android.text.style.CharacterStyle[]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   [0] = null
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   [1] = com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.views.ActivitySignUp$2 [id=0x130952c0]
D/LeakCanary﹕ * Instance of com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.views.ActivitySignUp$2
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   this$0 = com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.views.ActivitySignUp_ [id=0x13361800]
D/LeakCanary﹕ * Instance of com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.views.ActivitySignUp_
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   onViewChangedNotifier_ = org.androidannotations.api.view.OnViewChangedNotifier [id=0x13052dc0]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   birthday = null
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   buttonNext = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton [id=0x13459c00]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   confirmPassword = java.lang.String [id=0x132f01a0]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   editTextConformPassword = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText [id=0x13458400]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   editTextEmail = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText [id=0x1339b000]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   editTextFirstName = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText [id=0x13396c00]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   editTextLastName = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText [id=0x13398800]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   editTextPassword = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText [id=0x13456c00]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   email = java.lang.String [id=0x132f0040]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   facebook = com.facebook.android.Facebook [id=0x1307ee00]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   fbUserId = null
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   firstName = java.lang.String [id=0x132f0080]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   gender = null
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   lastName = java.lang.String [id=0x132f00e0]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   location = null
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mAsyncRunner = com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner [id=0x130952a0]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   password = java.lang.String [id=0x132f0140]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   termsOfUse = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView [id=0x1345a000]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   text = android.text.SpannableString [id=0x1310eaa0]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   fromFacebook = false
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   etHelpMessage = null
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mProgressHUD = null
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   positiveAction = null
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   showBusyAnimationRequesterCount = 0
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mDelegate = android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11 [id=0x12ecfd80]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mAllLoaderManagers = android.support.v4.util.SimpleArrayMap [id=0x131d80a0]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mContainer = android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$2 [id=0x13052db0]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mFragments = android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl [id=0x12f7cf60]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mHandler = android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$1 [id=0x1310ea80]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mLoaderManager = null
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mCheckedForLoaderManager = true
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mCreated = true
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mLoadersStarted = false
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mOptionsMenuInvalidated = false
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mReallyStopped = true
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mResumed = false
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mRetaining = false
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mStopped = true
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mActionBar = null
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mActivityInfo = android.content.pm.ActivityInfo [id=0x12db0180]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mActivityTransitionState = android.app.ActivityTransitionState [id=0x1304b600]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mAllLoaderManagers = android.util.ArrayMap [id=0x131c9d00]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mApplication = com.gmspartnersltd.earthmiles.globalstate.App [id=0x12c6e8c0]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mComponent = android.content.ComponentName [id=0x12f64150]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mContainer = android.app.Activity$1 [id=0x13052d70]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mCurrentConfig = android.content.res.Configuration [id=0x12f97520]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mDecor = null
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mDefaultKeySsb = null
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mEmbeddedID = null
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mEnterTransitionListener = android.app.SharedElementCallback$1 [id=0x70765ba8]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mExitTransitionListener = android.app.SharedElementCallback$1 [id=0x70765ba8]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mFragments = android.app.FragmentManagerImpl [id=0x12f7cef0]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mHandler = android.os.Handler [id=0x1310ea60]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mInstanceTracker = android.os.StrictMode$InstanceTracker [id=0x13052d90]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mInstrumentation = android.app.Instrumentation [id=0x12c33f70]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mIntent = android.content.Intent [id=0x12f3b300]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mLastNonConfigurationInstances = null
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mLoaderManager = null
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mMainThread = android.app.ActivityThread [id=0x12c2b100]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mManagedCursors = java.util.ArrayList [id=0x1310ea40]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mManagedDialogs = null
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mMenuInflater = null
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mParent = null
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mResultData = null
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mSearchManager = null
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mTitle = java.lang.String [id=0x12e6d7e0]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mToken = android.os.BinderProxy [id=0x12fe86a0]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mTranslucentCallback = null
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mUiThread = java.lang.Thread [id=0x73b43540]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mVoiceInteractor = null
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mWindow = com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow [id=0x12e5d580]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mWindowManager = android.view.WindowManagerImpl [id=0x1310ed20]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mCalled = true
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mChangeCanvasToTranslucent = false
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mChangingConfigurations = false
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mCheckedForLoaderManager = true
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mConfigChangeFlags = 0
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mDefaultKeyMode = 0
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mDestroyed = true
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mDoReportFullyDrawn = false
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mEnableDefaultActionBarUp = false
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mFinished = true
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mIdent = 24993652
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mLoadersStarted = false
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mResultCode = 0
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mResumed = false
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mStartedActivity = false
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mStopped = true
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mTemporaryPause = false
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mTitleColor = 0
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mTitleReady = true
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mVisibleBehind = false
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mVisibleFromClient = true
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mVisibleFromServer = false
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mWindowAdded = true
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mInflater = com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater [id=0x13152580]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mOverrideConfiguration = null
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mResources = android.content.res.Resources [id=0x12c33f20]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mTheme = android.content.res.Resources$Theme [id=0x1310ed40]
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mThemeResource = 2131689670
D/LeakCanary﹕ |   mBase = android.app.ContextImpl [id=0x12c81100]
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From [`AndroidExcludedRefs.java`](https://github.com/square/leakcanary/blob/master/leakcanary-android/src/main/java/com/squareup/leakcanary/AndroidExcludedRefs.java):

```
  // TextLine.sCached is a pool of 3 TextLine instances. TextLine.recycle() has had at least two
  // bugs that created memory leaks by not correctly clearing the recycled TextLine instances.
  // The first was fixed in android-5.1.0_r1:
  // https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit
  // /893d6fe48d37f71e683f722457bea646994a10bf

  // The second was fixed, not released yet:
  // https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit
  // /b3a9bc038d3a218b1dbdf7b5668e3d6c12be5ee4

  // Hack: to fix this, you could access TextLine.sCached and clear the pool every now and then
  // (e.g. on activity destroy).
```

#### Step 1: Access `TextLine.sCached`

```
public static class Utils {
    private static final Field TEXT_LINE_CACHED;

    static {
        Field textLineCached = null;
        try {
            textLineCached = Class.forName("android.text.TextLine").getDeclaredField("sCached");
            textLineCached.setAccessible(true);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        TEXT_LINE_CACHED = textLineCached;
    }

    public static void clearTextLineCache() {
        // If the field was not found for whatever reason just return.
        if (TEXT_LINE_CACHED == null) return;

        Object cached = null;
        try {
            // Get reference to the TextLine sCached array.
            cached = TEXT_LINE_CACHED.get(null);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //
        }
        if (cached != null) {
            // Clear the array.
            for (int i = 0, size = Array.getLength(cached); i < size; i ++) {
                Array.set(cached, i, null);
            }
        }
    }

    private Utils() {}
}
```

#### Step 2: Clear the pool

Call `Utils.clearTextLineCache()` when needed.

Comment: Thanks, is the Textline class this one? android.text.TextLine - because I could not find it using Android Studio editor

Comment: Yup, that's the one. It's also in the logcat: `GC ROOT static android.text.TextLine.sCached`. If for some reason you can't `import android.text.TextLine;` (perhaps it's hidden API or what not) use `Class.forName("android.text.TextLine")` instead of `TextLine.class`.

Comment: Thanks, yes I noticed it in the GC logcat as well, but still my editor can't find it. I used your method for the Textline.class line, but how can I do something similar for this line - TextLine[] cached = null;

Comment: @dowjones123 I didn't realize that at first, sorry. Check the updated code.

Comment: Thank you very much Eugen. This is really helpful - works fully.